# Export excel to PDF 0 shows as (?)

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

i have an excel file where one column has numbers starting from zero

[image]

when I save the file as PDF, these numbers are shown as

[image]

why is it so? why is 0 shown as an unidentified number here ? and the empty field also has that undefined mark, I have tried changing font that wont help, any other suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps, the "zero" is not really a zero. Usually, Excel will automatically remove the 0 in front of a number; as such, the "numbers" are actually Strings (thus wouldn't remove the 0, as it is not a number). To tell if the "0" is zero, copy and paste it individually into another cell and do `=0+3` (replace the 0 with the paste). It should result in 3 if "0" is a number. If you can, edit your post to include a copied/pasted line of one of the cells (as text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around, in my case there was an issue of format while converting to PDF. I simply saved these files via print to PDF Command and that did it for me